# How to show list label not value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show only auto-suggest list label text not value in following code snippet when we type y drop-list open and show yahoo when i yahoo on list it show yahoo URL in textbox not only yahoo i want to show only yahoo ,google or some thing else in label not in value

```js
var source = [ { value: "https://www.yahoo.com/",
                 label: "Yahoo"
               },
               { value: "https://www.google.com.pk",
                 label: "Google"
               }
             ];
    $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: source,
        select: function( event, ui ) { 
            window.location.href = ui.item.value;
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input id="autocomplete" />
```

Comment: I don't know why it not run on code snippet but it work in my localhost but it show value on selection not show label i want to show label like suggest result and on click or select label it will redirect to value

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `label` field from your source will be shown on the input field on selection or on focus but when you use `select:function()` callback, this behaviour is overridden and the `value` is updated to the text field.

**How to Fix:**

- Prevent the default behaviour of `select` callback to update the `value` to the text field.
- Update the value of the text field manually by setting the `.val()` of the textfield.

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
$(function () {
  var source = [{
    label: "Yahoo",
    value: "https://www.yahoo.com/"

}, {
    label: "Google",
    value: "https://www.google.com.pk"

}];
$("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: source,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault(); //prevent default beahaviour
        $(this).val(ui.item.label); //update the value manually
        window.location.href = ui.item.value;
    },
    focus: function (event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).val(ui.item.label);
    }
  });
});
```

[Live Demo @ JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/st141pbg/)

**Custom autocomplete:**

- Override the autocomplete `menu` rendering function `_renderMenu = function (ul, items) { ... }`
- Filter each `menu item` and render only the matching menu items (`._renderItem(ul, item);`) which starts with the searched text.
- When there are no items in the list, disable the `list` (removing the border) and revert back when there are items in the `list`.

[Custom autocomplete menu rendering @ JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/zvGKw/218)

*Note: I have prevented the default  behaviour on focus event as well, as it would also update the `value` to the text field.*

Comment: Thanks for your help very help full to me. Can you tell me one thing more that if we have one more label like Oogle so when we type O it show only Oogle not show yahoo or google b/c they also have O and also show result with scroll not long list. Thnx

Comment: U mean u need yahoo and google also to show when u type oogle in text field? I didn't understand about scroll part ,could you explain more

Comment: I mean if we have more thane 10 label words that start with O then when  we press O only those words show in list that start with O not those words show that also have O but in middle or end of word like I press O only Oogle will show not google or yahoo they also have O but not at start. And scroll means when press O list wil open with scroll bar b/c O is more than 10 words xcept to show as long list.

Comment: @Dami: when i type O i get `ooggle,Google and Yahoo`, so it does shows every word which has the typed character in it.http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/st141pbg/1/ . is this what u were talking about ?

Comment: i beleive there was no scroll bar for the autocomplete list when there were too many items, so I have restricted the list height to contain only minimum 10 items,http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/st141pbg/2/

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right when we press O i get oogle, Google and Yahoo, But I want only oogle because only oogle is start with O not google or yahoo they also have O but they not start with O they start with G or Y, Simply i want only those results which start with typed first character. Sory i know i bother you but you are best in jquery and i m starter, I am soo thanksful to you for helping me. I really appreciate your work.

Comment: thats may require overriding the default behaviour of autocomplete, let me see what i can do.

Comment: Yes absolutely that was I want's, Thankyyyyyy soooo much @dreamweiver you rocks broo. You don't know you save me from big big big trouble once again thank you EXCELLENT WORK.